# How to make netcdf plots like panoply in C++

Tags: netcdf

Im trying to make netcdf plots like what panoply does but i am not sure how to get this code

```
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkNetCDFCFReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkNetCDFCFReader>::New();
    reader->SetFileName("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/BOLTgui/BOLT/test.nc");

    reader->Update();

    vtkDataObject* dataObject = reader->GetOutput();
    vtkDataSet* dataSet = vtkDataSet::SafeDownCast(dataObject);
    vtkPointData* pointData = dataSet->GetPointData();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkContourFilter> contourFilter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkContourFilter>::New();
    contourFilter->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
    contourFilter->SetValue(0, 20); // set iso-value
    contourFilter->Update();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable> lookupTable = vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable>::New();
    lookupTable->SetNumberOfTableValues(256);
    lookupTable->Build();
    lookupTable->SetTableRange(contourFilter->GetOutput()->GetScalarRange());

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkColorTransferFunction> colorTransferFunction = vtkSmartPointer<vtkColorTransferFunction>::New();
    colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // blue
    colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(20.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // green
    colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(40.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); // yellow
    colorTransferFunction->AddRGBPoint(60.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // red

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputConnection(contourFilter->GetOutputPort());
    mapper->SetLookupTable(lookupTable);
    mapper->UseLookupTableScalarRangeOn();

    mapper->ScalarVisibilityOn();
    mapper->SetScalarModeToUsePointData();
    mapper->SetLookupTable(lookupTable);
    mapper->SetLookupTable(colorTransferFunction);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer < vtkRenderer>::New();
    renderer->AddActor(actor);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> interactor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    interactor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

    sf::WindowHandle handle = window.getSystemHandle();
    renderWindow->SetWindowInfo(reinterpret_cast<char*>(handle));
    interactor->Start();
   //While loop
       glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glPointSize(0.111f);

        // Calculate scaling factor
        float scalingFactor = 1.0f / 2.111f;

        vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSet> data = vtkDataSet::SafeDownCast(reader->GetOutput());
        for (vtkIdType i = 0; i < data->GetNumberOfCells(); i++) {
            vtkCell* cell = data->GetCell(i);
            vtkPoints* points = cell->GetPoints();
            double point1[3];
            double point2[3];
            double point3[3];
            points->GetPoint(0, point1);
            points->GetPoint(1, point2);
            points->GetPoint(2, point3);
            // Set the color for the first vertex
            glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            // Scale the point coordinates to adjust the size
            glVertex3f(point1[0] * scalingFactor, point1[1] * scalingFactor, point1[2] * scalingFactor);
            // Set the color for the second vertex
            glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(point2[0] * scalingFactor, point2[1] * scalingFactor, point2[2] * scalingFactor);
            // Set the color for the third vertex
            glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(point3[0] * scalingFactor, point3[1] * scalingFactor, point3[2] * scalingFactor);
        }
        glEnd();
```

this code currently displays the netcdf data like this  [image: like this]
but i am trying to render the netcdf data in opengl like this [image: like this panoply plot]
what do i need to do to modify the code to render the netcdf data like in the panoply plot

Comment: This is probably a question best asked on the NetCDF forums. To me, it looks like you have an indexing error where one point for each square is wrongly indexed (namely, the top left point).